# $f$ is integrable over $A := Int(S)$, and $\int_S f = \int_A f$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : S \to R$ be a bounded continuous function on a bounded set $S \subset R^n$. Show that if $f$ is integrable over $S$, then $f$ is integrable over $A := Int(S)$, and $\int_S f = \int_A f$. Show that the converse is not true?

$Int(S)$ is the interior of $S$.

Require Hints for the problem.

Comment: Not exactly true. $S$ could be the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ and $f$ could be the identity, hence $$\int_S f\,dx=\frac12\\ \int_{\operatorname{int}S} f\,dx=\int_\emptyset f\,dx=0$$

Comment: And even worse: same $f$, but with $S'=S\cup (2,3)$ ($S$ is the one before).